# Explicitly invoke SIG_DFL/SIG_IGN handlers on Linux

Tags: linux, signals

I've blocked, and then waited for a signal via the following code:

```
sigset_t set;
sigfillset(&set); // all signals
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL); // block all signals
siginfo_t info;
int signum = sigwaitinfo(&set, &info); // wait for next signal
struct sigaction act;
sigaction(signum, NULL, &act); // get the current handler for the signal
act.sa_handler(signum); // invoke it
```

The last line generates a segmentation fault, as the handler is set to `SIG_DFL` (defined as `0`). How can I manually invoke the default handler if it's set to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`? Also note that `SIG_IGN` is defined as `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered you cannot invoke SIG_DFL and SIG_IGN *per se*.  However, you can more-or-less mimic their behavior.

Briefly, imitating normal signal disposition would be:

- quite easy for user-defined `sa_handler`s
- easy enough for SIG_IGN, with the caveat that you'd need to waitpid() in the case of CHLD
- straightforward but unpleasant for SIG_DFL, re-raising to let the kernel do its magic.

Does this do what you want?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Manually dispose of a signal, mimicking the behavior of current
 * signal dispositions as best we can.  We won't cause EINTR, for
 * instance.
 *
 * FIXME:  save and restore errno around the SIG_DFL logic and
 *         SIG_IGN/CHLD logic.
 */
void dispatch_signal(const int signo) {
    int stop = 0;
    sigset_t oset;
    struct sigaction curact;

    sigaction(signo, NULL, &curact);

    /* SIG_IGN => noop or soak up child term/stop signals (for CHLD) */
    if (SIG_IGN == curact.sa_handler) {
        if (SIGCHLD == signo) {
          int status;
          while (waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED) > 0) {;}
        } 
        return;
    }

    /* user defined => invoke it */
    if (SIG_DFL != curact.sa_handler) {
        curact.sa_handler(signo);
        return;
    }

    /* SIG_DFL => let kernel handle it (mostly).
     *
     *  We handle noop signals ourselves -- "Ign" and "Cont", which we
     *  can never intercept while stopped.
     */
    if (SIGURG == signo || SIGWINCH == signo || SIGCONT == signo) return;

    /*  Unblock CONT if this is a "Stop" signal, so that we may later be
     *  woken up.
     */
    stop = (SIGTSTP == signo || SIGTTIN == signo || SIGTTOU == signo);
    if (stop) {
        sigset_t sig_cont;

        sigemptyset(&sig_cont);
        sigaddset(&sig_cont, SIGCONT);
        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sig_cont, &oset);
    }

    /*  Re-raise, letting the kernel do the work:
     *     - Set exit codes and corefiles for "Term" and "Core"
     *     - Halt us and signal WUNTRACED'ing parents for "Stop"
     *     - Do the right thing if we forgot to handle any special
     *       signals or signals yet to be introduced
     */
    kill(getpid(), signo);

    /* Re-block CONT, if needed */
    if (stop) sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oset, NULL);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
(in response to OP's excellent questions)

> *1: does this slot in after the sigwaitinfo?*

Yes.  Something like:

```
... block signals ...
signo = sigwaitinfo(&set, &info);
dispatch_signal(signo);
```

> *2: Why not raise those signals handled by SIG_IGN, they'll be ignored anyway*

It's slightly more efficient to noop in userspace than by three syscalls (re-raise, unmask, re-mask).  Moreover, CHLD has special semantics when SIG_IGNored.

> *3: Why treat SIGCHLD specially?*

Originally (check answer edits) I didn't -- re-raised it in the SIG_IGN case,
because [IGNored CHLD signals tell the kernel to automatically reap children](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).

However, I changed it because ["natural" CHLD signals carry information about
the terminated process](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/signal.h.html) (at least PID, status, and real UID).
User-generated CHLD signals don't carry the same semantics, and, in my testing,
IGNoring them doesn't cause 2.6 to autoreap queued zombies whose SIGCHLD
was "missed."  So, I do it myself.

> *4: Why are "stop" related signals unblocking CONT.  Will not invoking the default handler for CONT unstop the process?*

If we're stopped (not executing) and CONT is blocked, we will never receive the
signal to wake us up!

> *5: Why not call raise instead of the kill line you've given?*

Personal preference; `raise()` would work, too.

Comment: I like your attempt, a few things are concerning/confusing; 1: does this slot in after the sigwaitinfo? 2: Why not raise those signals handled by SIG_IGN, they'll be ignored anyway? 3: Why treat SIGCHLD specially? If the default does not wait for children, neither should this. 4: Why are "stop" related signals unblocking CONT. Will not invoking the default handler for CONT unstop the process? 5: Why not call `raise` instead of the `kill` line you've given?

Comment: Great answers, thanks. I'll point out that you don't make use of the special SIGCHLD info anyway. A good point regarding SIGCONT being blocked, as we can't process it through `sigwaitinfo` while stopped?

Comment: Matt, I access that info through waitpid()s interface, FWIW.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `raise` and `kill`. "_The `raise()` function sends the signal sig to the executing thread._" (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/raise.html) "_The `kill()` function will send a signal to a process (...)_" (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/kill.html). Whether a signal is send to a process or a specific thread of a process matters with blocking and delivery context.

Comment: Here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/raise.html we can better see how `raise` depends on whether threads are supported or not. Only without support for threads is `raise` equivalent to `kill` with `getpid()`.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 mistakes in your code :
1) You should reverse the last two lines like this :

```
act.sa_handler(signum);
sigaction(signum, NULL, &act);
```

2) You must pass a function handler to the fiedl sa_handler instead of a int. The prototype of the function shoudl look like this :

```
   /**
    *some where in you code
     */
     void handler (int signal){ /*your code*/}
   /**
    *
    */      
    act.sa_handler = handler;
```

If you want the default handler to be invoked, you should set the field **sa_handler** to **SIG_DFL** and it should work.

Comment: I'm afraid you're answering another question :)

Comment: No, this is the 2 things i saw in your code. 
But the answer of your question is in the last sentence

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the way to do it.

Only suggestion I have is to look into the `man 7 signal` and perform manually the action according the table you see there. `Ign` is nothing. `Core` is call to `abort()`. `Term` is `_exit()`.

Of course you can also set signal handler back to SIG_DFL and then `kill(getpid(),THE_SIG)` (or its equivalent `raise(THE_SIG)`). (I personally do not like `raise` because on some systems it might produce some messages on stderr.)

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, since I've applied a `sigprocmask()` for all signals to the current signal already.

Comment: +1 You'd have to unblock just that signal for SIG_DFL, but would have to be careful about SIGSTOP.  See my answer.