# How to provide extend-on-write functionality for memory mapped files in Linux?

Tags: linux, posix, aix

I'm working on porting some code from AIX to Linux. Parts of the code use the [`shmat()` system call](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf2/shmat.htm) to create new files. When used with `SHM_MAP` in a writable mode, one can extend the file beyond its original length (of zero, in my case):

> When a file is mapped onto a segment, the file is referenced by accessing the segment. The memory paging system automatically takes care of the physical I/O. References beyond the end of the file cause the file to be extended in page-sized increments. The file cannot be extended beyond the next segment boundary.

(A "segment" in AIX is a 256 MB chunk of address space, and a "page" is usually 4 KB.)

What I would *like* to do on Linux is the following:

- Reserve a large-ish chunk of address space (it doesn't have to be as big as 256 MB, these aren't such large files)
- Set up the page protection bits so that a segfault is generated on the first access to a page that hasn't been touched before
- On a page fault, clear the "cause a page fault" bit and allocate committed memory for the page, allowing the write (or read) that caused the page fault to proceed
- Upon closing the shared memory area, write the modified pages to a file

I know I can do this on Windows with the [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, the `PAGE_GUARD` memory protection bit, and a [structured exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). What is the corresponding method on Linux to do the same? Is there perhaps a better way to implement this extend-on-write functionality on Linux?

I've already considered:

- using `mmap()` with some fixed large-ish size, but I can't tell how much of the file was written to by the application code
- allocating an anonymous shared memory area of large-ish size, but again I can't tell how much of the area has been written
- `mmap()` by itself does not seem to provide any facility to extend the length of the backing file

Naturally I would like to do this with only minimal changes to the application code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *very* similar to a homework I once did. Basically I had a list of "pages" and a list of "frames", with associated information. Using `SIGSEGV` I would catch faults and alter the memory protection bits as necessary. I'll include parts that you may find useful.

#### Create mapping. Initially it has no permissions.

```
int w_create_mapping(size_t size, void **addr)
{

    *addr = mmap(NULL,
            size * w_get_page_size(),
            PROT_NONE,
            MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,
            -1,
            0
    );

    if (*addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

#### Install signal handler

```
int w_set_exception_handler(w_exception_handler_t handler)
{
    static struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGSEGV);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, &previous_action) < 0)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

#### Exception handler

```
static void fault_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    void *address;      /* the address that faulted */

    /* Memory location which caused fault */
    address = info->si_addr;

    if (FALSE == page_fault(address)) {
        _exit(1);
    }
}
```

#### Increasing protection

```
int w_protect_mapping(void *addr, size_t num_pages, w_prot_t protection)
{
    int prot;

    switch (protection) {
    case PROTECTION_NONE:
        prot = PROT_NONE;
        break;
    case PROTECTION_READ:
        prot = PROT_READ;
        break;
    case PROTECTION_WRITE:
        prot = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
        break;
    }

    if (mprotect(addr, num_pages * w_get_page_size(), prot) < 0)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

I can't publicly make it all available since the team is likely to use that same homework again.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This is very similar in structure to what I did previously on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Allocate a big buffer however you like and then use mprotect()* system call to make the tail of the buffer read only and register a signal handler for SIGSEGV to note where in the before writes have been made and use mprotect() yet again to enable writes.

- http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect

Answer (score 0):

I've contemplated similar things myself, and haven't found any way for `mmap()` to extend the backing file either.

Currently, I plan on trying two alternatives:

- manually manage filesize, extending it myself and `mremap()`'ing afterwards
- create a sparse file and hope that the VM would allocate needed sectors when flushing dirty pages.

honestly, I don't think sparse files would work, but it's worth a try.