# What is real use of return type of signal function

Tags: c, signals

Signal function return the value of old handler , but what is the situation where old handler value may useful,  because most of the places we don't check return value of signal function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two situations when the value of the old handler is useful:

- You want to implement a new handler that calls the old handler at some point during its run, or
- You want to replace an old handler with a new one, and put the old one back at some point.

In both cases you store the old handler returned by the replacement function.

Comment: thanks for your ans , but can you please give a example where we will like to call old handler , I mean , in which condition we will like to call old handler again?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13290134/335858) has a very detailed code example, also explaining how to deal with `SIG_DFL` and `SIG_IGN`.

Comment: One example why you'd need to chain signal handlers is JNI code that needs to clean up on abnormal termination of the JVM.  To do that, you'd install your own SIGABRT handler, and save off original handler - which is the JVM's SIGABRT handler.  When your SIGABRT handler gets called because the JVM is terminating abnormally, you do your cleanup, then call the original SIGABRT handler.