# What 's the meaning of the number 1 in SIG_IGN macro definition?

Tags: c, linux, sigpipe

```
#define SIG_IGN     (void (*)(int))1
#define SIG_HOLD    (void (*)(int))5
#define SIG_ERR     ((void (*)(int))-1)
```

I know what `(void (*)(int))` means: cast unknown_name into pointer to function (int) returning void.

But what's the meaning of the following `1`?

Comment: Where do the "5" and "-1" in your title come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant is used so that it can be distinguished from a valid function pointer.  It has no meaning in itself (other than being distinct).

For example:

```
#define SIG_DFL ((__sighandler_t)0)     /* default signal handling */
#define SIG_IGN ((__sighandler_t)1)     /* ignore signal */
#define SIG_ERR ((__sighandler_t)-1)    /* error return from signal */
```

None of those constant values is something that you could call as a valid function address.  So they are useful as special values that can be used to say how to handle signals.

POSIX by the way does not mention these constants `-1`, `0` or `1`, preferring to say only *symbolic constants* (in the expected place, anyway): [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

Further reading:

- [executing default signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015498/executing-default-signal-handler)
- [24.3.1 Basic Signal Handling](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html) (The GNU C library)

Answer (score 1):

Add a useful reference material as to the accepted answer.

From *APUE*:

> If we examine the system’s header , we will probably find
>   declarations of the form
>
> ```
> #define SIG_ERR (void (*)()) -1
> #define SIG_DFL (void (*)())  0
> #define SIG_IGN (void (*)())  1
> ```
>
> These constants can be used in place of the ‘‘pointer to a function
>   that takes an integer argument and returns nothing,’’ the second
>   argument to `signal`, and the return value from `signal`. **The three
>   values used for these constants need not be −1, 0, and 1. They must be
>   three values that can never be the address of any declarable function.**
>   Most UNIX systems use the values shown.

Yes, it ensures you will get a error when you try to do stupid things [like me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390218/why-cant-i-call-the-function-signal-handler-returned-by-function-signal) (maybe other (useful/stupid) things, I don't know):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    printf("hahahah\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*f1)(int);
    f1 = signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    f1(3);  //Get signal SIGSEGV and failed
            //Here I am calling SIG_DFL(3).
    raise(SIGINT);
}
```

Here calling `f1(3)` equals calling `SIG_DFL(3)`, every function has an address but `SIG_DFL` (0) is not a valid one, so I get `SIGSEGV` error.

> `SIGSEGV` This signal indicates that the process has made an invalid
>   memory reference (which is usually a sign that the program has a bug,
>   such as dereferencing an uninitialized pointer).

Comment: Haha, nice example!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala haha, I am trying to complete this and the other similar question,  based on my silly experience. :D