# SIG_IGN, SIG_DFL, SIG_ERR 's definition

Tags: c, linux, signals

In `<signal.h>` there are definition of following:

`#define SIG_ERR (void (*)())-1`

`#define SIG_DFL (void (*)())0`

`#define SIG_IGN (void (*)())1`

I think `void (*)()` means it's a function pointer that return type is void and parameter is void(because there is empty between parenthesis).

But in `signal()` function, the second argument type is `void (*func)(int)`.

Then, why the definition above three things are `void (*)()`. And, also, what means the number `-1` `0` `1` in the definition?

How can I interpret these definitions?

Comment: These are (small) integer values cast to pointer_to_function. The implementation can distinguish them from real function pointers, so they will never be invoked (the non-existing functions will not be called) , but are treated special. And you don't have to interpret these values, just use the symbolic constants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What 's the meaning of the number 1 in SIG\_IGN macro definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105452/what-s-the-meaning-of-the-number-1-in-sig-ign-macro-definition)

Comment: Why do you want to interpret this file? It may contain implementation internals not meant to look like valid C code

Comment: I just see the definition in the book "apue"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definitions are different from mine. If I preprocess the following file:

```
#include <signal.h>
SIG_IGN
SIG_DFL
SIG_ERR
```

The last 3 lines in the preprocessor output are

```
% gcc -E sigtest.c|tail -n3
((__sighandler_t) 1)
((__sighandler_t) 0)
((__sighandler_t) -1)
```

and the typedefs are

```
typedef __signalfn_t *__sighandler_t;
```

and

```
typedef void __signalfn_t(int);
```

from `asm-generic/signal-defs.h`. So it must be that you have some old headers.

However, this is not C++, but C. Empty parentheses in C mean that the function arguments are not declared / that the function can take any number of arguments. This has been considered obsolescent since C89 standard. Yet, a value of type `void (*)()` would be compatible with `void (*)(int)`.

---

The values -1, 0 and 1 are non-portable magic constants that have meaning only to the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I interpret these definitions?

`#define SIG_DFL (void (*)()) 0` is merely an ordinary `#define` with **casting**.

You must know `#define HAHA 2` (a `int` with value 2),
so what about `#define HAHA (float) 2`(a `float` with value 2) ,
and `#define HAHA (int*) 2` (a pointer to `int`/`int*` with value(the pointer's value) 2).

So `#define SIG_DFL (void (*)()) 0` means it's defining a (function) **pointer**, and the pointer's value is `0`.

Again, `SIG_DFL` is a constant with value `2`, and its type is `void(*)(int)`, a (function) **pointer**.

As for function pointers, it's something you can call directly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int a){
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("hahaha\n");
}

int main(){
    foo(3); //you can call foo() directly
    //or you may call it through a matched function pointer
    void (*foo_ptr)(int);   // I am declaring a function pointer
    foo_ptr =  foo;
    foo_ptr(3);  //same as calling foo(3)
}
```

---

> Why the definition above three things are `void (*)()`?

Because it's what the `signal` function requires. The `signal` function requires its handlers to have function signature like `void (*)(int)`.

So the fake functions (`SIG_DFL`, `SIG_IGN`) also need to be the `void (*)(int)` type.

Note the `SIG_ERR` is used to indicate a handler setting failure.

See the parameter description of **handler** from https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal.

---

> What does the number -1 0 1 in the definition mean?

See [What 's the meaning of the number 1 in SIG_IGN macro definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105452/what-s-the-meaning-of-the-number-1-in-sig-ign-macro-definition)

---

I have to say at first I was mainly stuck in the pattern `#define SIG_DFL (void (*)()) 0`, I didn't realize it is a casting.. :)