# How to install a signal handler to call a function when 'SIGINT' is received

Tags: c, signals

I'm supposed to install a signal handler to call the function `stopContinue()` when I receive `SIGINT`. Here is my code snippet in C, but I'm not sure if this correct. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
struct sigaction act;

memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
action.sa_flags = 0; 
action.sa_handler = stopContinue;
sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
```

Does this look roughly correct?

There is a discussion on using sigaction vs. action, and the use of flags here that is different than another question, this is not a dupe.

Comment: What happened when you tried to run it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch Ctrl-C in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c)

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=c+signal+handler

Comment: You also need to clear the set of blocked signals, using e.g. `sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);` after the `memset()`.

Comment: You haven't checked whether the code is currently ignoring interrupts; if it is, you probably shouldn't re-enable interrupt handling.  This is a standard issue.  With `sigaction()`, you can use `sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &act)` to find the current signal handling state — you could then modify that and set a new state more or less as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `sigaction` if you're not even going to use the struct's `sa_flags` member? To call `stopContinue` when <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is pressed, you can use:

```
signal(SIGINT, stopContinue);
```

If you simply want to *ignore* <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, you can make it even easier:

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

`SIG_IGN` is a [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35105484/6850771) to ignore signals.

Comment: Because [`signal()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) is only portable if used with `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`, whereas [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) is the proper POSIX.1 standard function to use here, your suggestion is bad.

Comment: @NominalAnimal POSIX isn't exactly portable, though... **Never mind. Not what I meant.**

Comment: Don't be ridiculous. POSIX semantics are used in Linux, BSDs, macOS, Solaris, Tru64, and so on -- basically everywhere except Windows. It is Windows stuff and idiotic suggestions like this that are not portable.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Does the behavior of `signal` vary enough across POSIX that writing `signal(SIGNAL, FUNCTION)` on two different platforms *may not call `FUNCTION` when `SIGNAL` is recieved?*

Comment: On SysV Unix boxes, *`FUNCTION`* would only be called for the first signal delivery, and the disposition reset for the second; meaning two Ctrl+C rapidly in succession would usually kill the process. BSD `signal()` installs the handler as if with `.sa_flags = SA_RESTART` was specified via sigaction, so that the delivery will not interrupt a blocking syscall. Since the signal handler typically just sets a `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag, and relies on the main processing loop to be interrupted so that the flag is examined, this would not occur on BSDs.

Comment: On all the systems I mentioned, using `sigaction()` with `.sa_flags = 0;` the semantics are always the same: the delivery of the signal to the user function will interrupt a blocking syscall (in the same thread; in a multithreaded process the kernel may choose any thread that is not blocking the signal), and the typical `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag scenario will work. A typical example of a main loop being interrupted is `accept()`ing a new connection. If interrupted by a signal, it will return `-1` with `errno == EINTR`.