# Why can't I call the function (signal handler) returned by function signal?

Tags: c, signals

After figuring out the signature of the `signal` function, I modified the example given by https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal.

But why can't I call the function (the signal handler) returned by the `signal`, instead I can call it direclty ?

---

`void (*signal( int sig, void (*handler) (int))) (int);`

The `signal` function returns a pointer to function, which is `void (*)(int)`.

> #### Return value
>
> **Previous signal handler** on success or `SIG_ERR` on failure (setting a signal handler can be disabled on some implementations).

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    printf("hahahah\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*f1)(int);
    f1 = signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    f1(3);  //Get signal SIGSEGV and failed
//    signal_handler(3); //OK
    raise(SIGINT);

}
```

I know it might look like a meaningless question, but the point is, `f1` points to `signal_handler`, so calling `f1(3)` is just like calling `signal_handler(3)`, I don't understand why the latter is ok but not the former, there should be not "tricks" that can make between these two calling function statments, I think.

Comment: The previous signal handler isn't necessarily a pointer to a function.

Comment: @user3386109 Hmm, don't understand. `signal` returns `void (*)(int)`, isn't this a pointer to function  (function pointer) and can call it?

Comment: In response to the edit: `f1` does not point to `signal_handler`. It points to the **previous** signal handler. You can use `printf` with the `%p` format specifier to display `f1` and `signal_handler` and you'll see that they are different.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, you're right.  Thanks for telling me to use `%p` :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
f1 = signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
```

`f1` is assigned a **previous signal handler** (which is not `signal_handler` in the code) which may not be a pointer to a function that you can call with an `int` argument.

To achieve the effect you want to have define a second signal handler and assign it to `f1` after the line mentioned above.

Something like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void signal_handler2(int signal)
{
    printf("hahahah2222\n");
}

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    printf("hahahah\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*f1)(int);
    f1 = signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    f1 = signal(SIGINT, signal_handler2);
    f1(3);  //Success
    signal_handler2(3); //OK
    raise(SIGINT);    
}
```

Output:

```
hahahah
hahahah2222
hahahah2222
```

See Live **[Demo](https://tio.run/##jZBBC4IwGIbv@xUfdplRDe1odQuRoA5GpyCGmzpYM9S6hL/dtqUSEtS327vnfb6xZJ4lSduiiVCJvDMOq0pkispFvvnMaiYKE6FHIRi8kUtOFZO89LFQdZe56IlAz63UWYqdnNrj6zkrxw1Qg746fiuGuiGvVChsND1slXiaeq4xadCEqQfrTorjKIz2x9lo7d@gP5B46QYAhIS8fzDoSrwNT6BRSKmQnFl2/EumSMhhZy9LKireLdNu1LTtCw)**

Comment: So it is.. The documentation is always kinda misleading. Since I've registered a new handler, naturally I would think that **previous handler** should be the one I just register... Thank you btw ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 values that `signal()` can return that are not pointers to real functions:

1. `SIG_DFL` — typically `((void (*)(int))0)`
2. `SIG_IGN` — typically `((void (*)(int))1)`
3. `SIG_ERR` — typically `((void (*)(int))-1)`

When a program starts, the signals are either in `SIG_IGN` or `SIG_DFL` mode; you can subsequently set them to another value.

When you call `f1 = signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);`, you get back one of `SIG_DFL` and `SIG_IGN` — and neither of those is a pointer to a callable function (even though their type is pointer to a function of the correct type).

Comment: What does the pattern `#define HAHA   (void(*)(int))   2` mean? I guess it's defining a function **pointer**, and the pointer's value is `2`. But I am only familiar with the pattern like `#define CONSTANT value`. I tried to imitate by doing `#define HAHA float 2.3` but failed :(. It's the first time that I see this kind of usage, could you give me some hint or may be some reference? I see 2 other questions on SO but the answer isn't really helpful.

Comment: Yes; `HAHA` is a function pointer with numeric value 2.  It can't safely be used in `(*HAHA)(3)` or `HAHA(3)` — both notations work, but the former  was necessary before the C89 standard was published.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks. Any idea where can I find this usage on some official documentation or standard?

Comment: Well, the notation `(void (*)(int))` followed by a value is a cast  of that value to a pointer to function.  Casting `2` (or `1` or `0` or `-1`) is probably not officially documented anywhere.  A quick scan of the C11 standard didn't reveal anything useful.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. It's nothing special but casting. Ya, that's what I need. Then definitely I can do `#define HAHA (float) 2.3`. Thanksssssss!