# Restore a default behavior of CTRL+C after using SIGINT

Tags: c, linux, signals

I need to write a function which restores default behavior of CTRL+C (terminating process) after pressing CTRL+\
Here's my program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sig_int(int sig)
{

    printf("U PRESSED CTRL+C\n");
}
void sig_quit(int sig){
            printf("CTRL+C NOW DO ITS KILLING JOB\n");

}
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    signal(SIGINT,sig_int);
    signal(SIGQUIT, sig_quit);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for all the help and descriptions to better understanding :)

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015498/executing-default-signal-handler especially `SIG_DFL`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler

Comment: Also you should most probably use `sigaction`

Comment: And you should not use non-async-signal-safe functions in a signal handler.  Per [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188):  "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the man page on my machine:

> To set the default action of the signal to occur as listed above, func should be SIG_DFL.

so `signal(SIQUIT, SIG_DFL)` if I've understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`signal` returns the previously configured handler, store it somewhere and then use `signal` to restore it whenever you want. Also SIG_DFL points to the C run-time's default handler, but that's not always the right one to use.

Comment: Wonder what the down-vote is about?